# How to access child item controllers from an Ember arraycontroller?

Tags: validation, ember.js

Is there a way, we can access child item controller objects from the parent arraycontroller?
In my particular case, I have a QuestionController that has answersValidation array. I am using {{render 'answers-validation' answersValidation}}. Now, when I need to validate: I can validate the Question but how do I validate the 'answersValidation' array as well. Each of the answer validate returns a promise. I have an AnswerValidationController for each answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show some code and be more specific about what "validate" means?

Comment: needs : ['directory/filename']   ..  on controller u can go this.get('controllers.directory/filename').youNowHaveAccess;